# Using variables with Node Email Templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Very confused from the docs on how to use variables from Node in my Node Email Templates. (I'm using this with Nodemailer as well).

Here's my code. I want to pass in an object to the template and render the variables within the resulting HTML:

```
var sendTicket = transporter.templateSender(new EmailTemplate('templates/ticket'), {
      from: 'some@address.com',
  });

  sendTicket({
      to: 'fake@address.com',
      subject: 'Email Subject'
  }, {
      user: "Jim",
      address: "123 Easy St"
  }, function(err, info){
      if(err){
         console.log('Error');
      }else{
          console.log('Email sent');
      }
  });
```

Jade (in `templates/ticket/html.jade`):

```
html
  head
    - var user = user
    - var address = address        
  body
    h1= user
    h2= address
```

However, this sends a blank email. How do I do this properly?